# How to extract the title from the given anchor tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to get the xpath to extract the title from this html line.

Not got anything useful because cssClass can change with time so the code may break. I think that since href and text in this tag are both the name that I want to extract maybe use a equality condition.

```
<a class="FPmhX notranslate nJAzx" title="ceorackz_adpp" href="/ceorackz_adpp/">ceorackz_adpp</a>
```

I want python code compatible either using a selenium API call or normal regex to get the title or text of this anchor tag.

Comment: please add your some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the `HTML` element in inspect section. 
Then go to `Copy > Copy XPath` . 
Then use this code

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("copied_xpath").get_attribute("title")
href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("copied_xpath").get_attribute("href")
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("copied_xpath").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any xpath from below list:

```
//a[@title='ceorackz_adpp']

//a[text()='ceorackz_adpp']

//a[@title='ceorackz_adpp' and text()='ceorackz_adpp']
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the title i.e. **ceorackz_adpp** from the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.notranslate[href='/ceorackz_adpp/']"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "ceorackz_adpp"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'notranslate') and @href='/ceorackz_adpp/']"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure, yet I'd guess that, maybe an expression similar to:

```
title="(.+?)">\s*(.+?)\s*<
```

might be a point to start.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFB5OT/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"title=\"(.+?)\">\s*(.+?)\s*<"

test_str = "<a class=\"FPmhX notranslate nJAzx\" title=\"ceorackz_adpp\" href=\"/ceorackz_adpp/\">ceorackz_adpp</a>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```